# Async task not working well

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I have used Async task to send a mail when user presses the button "b" but its showing an error and the error is "`Error while executing doInBackground`" and "`First Activity has leaked a Window`"

```
    public class FirstActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
    {
    Button b;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
          progress.setMessage("Loading...");
          new MyTask(progress).execute();


        Intent i=new Intent(this,newclass.class);
        startActivity(i);
            }


        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
          private ProgressDialog progress;

        public MyTask(ProgressDialog progress) 
        {
            this.progress = progress;

        }
          public void onPreExecute()
          {

              super.onPreExecute();
              progress.show();

          }

          public Void doInBackground(Void... unused)
          {

              String detail="sending mmail";
              new MainActivity(detail);
            return null;
          }

          public void onPostExecute(Void unused) 
          {
            progress.dismiss();

          }
        }


}
```

Comment: are you getting error add the logcat output

Comment: sorry i m not able to post logcat here.

Comment: but the  errors are as i have mentoined

Answer (score 1):

try to use this method in doInBackground...

```
    public Void doInBackground(Void... unused)
      {
                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {

                public void run() 
                                    {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          String detail="sending mmail";
          new MainActivity(detail);
        return null;
                }
            });

      }
```

Comment: used it bro. But the thing is that progress is shown just for a fraction before it intents to next page. Progress should start immediately after clicking on submit button.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are starting a new activity immediately after starting your progress dialog (the dialog loses its context).
You need to move it to onPostExecute().

```
public void onPostExecute(Void unused){
    progress.dismiss();
    Intent i = new Intent(this,newclass.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: used it bro. But the thing is that progress is shown just for a fraction before it intents to next page. Progress should start immediately after clicking on submit button.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to navigate to a new `Activity`, `MainActivity`, while the `ProgressDialog` is still on. That is causing the memory leak.

Comment: yeahh i know this..
After googling my errors i knw wot u r saying but i am not able to remove the errors.
If you can make changes to code and than post the code than it will be fine

Comment: Navneeet, why dont you just add the ProgressDialog in the MainActivity and remove it from FirstActivity and this way there will be no memory leak.